Latest syslog-ng problem reading source file - "Follow-mode file source not found..."
I have the latest docker image of syslog-ng and cannot run it properly:
docker run --privileged -d -it -v "$PWD/syslog-ng.conf":/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf --name syslog-ng balabit/syslog-ng:latest -edv
My syslog-ng conf:
@version: 4.8
@include "scl.conf"

source s_local {
        file("/var/log/test_log")
};

destination d_local {
        file("/var/log/destination_log");
};

log {
        source(s_local);
        destination(d_local);
};

The output of the previous command is:
Follow-mode file source not found, deferring open; filename='/var/log/test_log'
Follow mode file still does not exist; filename='/var/log/test_log'

Obviously I am missing something. Can you help please. Tried a lot of things already. OS is Almalinux 8 with disabled SeLinux.

Perhaps test_log does not exist in the filesystem, you ever figure that? Do you have access to the /var/log directory? What is it's chmod? What is it chown? Which user are you running the docker from? Please include these details

@Dimitar, As I already mentioned tried a lot of things and yes: test_log exists. /var/log standard permissions: drwxr-xr-x.  18 root  root  4.0K Aug 29 07:20 log. Running the docker image with root for testing purposes.

can you try running docker exec -it syslog-ng ls /var/log/test_log?

Output:
[root@33829 ~]# docker exec -it syslog-ng ls /var/log/test_log
ls: cannot access '/var/log/test_log': No such file or directory
[root@33829 ~]# ls -lahtr /var/log/test_log
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 29 08:10 /var/log/test_log



@Dimitar, I think I got the problem where is.

I am guessing this is a mounting issue. Can you try mounting the /var/log/ of the system to the container:
docker run --privileged -d -it \   -v "$PWD/syslog-ng.conf":/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf \   -v "/var/log":/var/log \   --name syslog-ng balabit/syslog-ng:latest -edv

I am guessing that you are also suspecting that it is a mounting issue, as the container and the system are not synced up. I think that just adding -v "/var/log":/var/log in your original command will solve the issue. I might be wrong, though.

The fix of the issue is mentioned in the comments:
docker run --privileged -d -it \   
-v "$PWD/syslog-ng.conf":/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf \   
-v "/var/log":/var/log \   
--name syslog-ng balabit/syslog-ng:latest -edv 

The key here is -v "/var/log":/var/log, which makes sure that the container has the /var/www directory of the system mounted in its /var/www, giving it access to the test_log in it.

You can approve the edit and the answer to the question yourself, to make it easier for users in the future to find it if they stumble on the same or a similar problem.
